# ads don't show in mingle forum plugin?

Tags: css, plugins

i use mingle forum plugin. ads not show here.i want to use this ads format code. but not show this plugin. show only html code. not ads. how i can solve this problem. [my site](http://forum.dewdropzone.com).

```
clicksor_enable_pop = true; clicksor_frequencyCap = -1;
durl = '';clicksor_enable_layer_pop = false;
//default banner house ad url 
clicksor_default_url = '';
clicksor_banner_border = ''; clicksor_banner_ad_bg = '';
clicksor_banner_link_color = ''; clicksor_banner_text_color = '';
clicksor_layer_border_color = '';
clicksor_layer_ad_bg = ''; clicksor_layer_ad_link_color = '';
clicksor_layer_ad_text_color = ''; clicksor_text_link_bg = '';
clicksor_text_link_color = ''; clicksor_enable_text_link = true;
clicksor_layer_banner = false;
```

[affiliate marketing](http://www.yesadvertising.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solve my problem. i want to show it for other people who face this problem.

Go to /mingle-forum/fs-admin/fs-admin.php and find this code

```
            $mingleforum->ads_options = array(  'mf_ad_above_forum_on'          => $_POST['mf_ad_above_forum_on'],
                                                'mf_ad_above_forum'             => wp_kses_post($_POST['mf_ad_above_forum_text']),
                                                'mf_ad_below_forum_on'          => $_POST['mf_ad_below_forum_on'],
                                                'mf_ad_below_forum'             => wp_kses_post($_POST['mf_ad_below_forum_text']),
                                                'mf_ad_above_branding_on'       => $_POST['mf_ad_above_branding_on'],
                                                'mf_ad_above_branding'          => wp_kses_post($_POST['mf_ad_above_branding_text']),
                                                'mf_ad_above_info_center_on'    => $_POST['mf_ad_above_info_center_on'],
                                                'mf_ad_above_info_center'       => wp_kses_post($_POST['mf_ad_above_info_center_text']),
                                                'mf_ad_above_quick_reply_on'    => $_POST['mf_ad_above_quick_reply_on'],
                                                'mf_ad_above_quick_reply'       => wp_kses_post($_POST['mf_ad_above_quick_reply_text']),
                                                'mf_ad_above_breadcrumbs_on'    => $_POST['mf_ad_above_breadcrumbs_on'],
                                                'mf_ad_above_breadcrumbs'       => wp_kses_post($_POST['mf_ad_above_breadcrumbs_text']),
                                                'mf_ad_below_first_post_on'     => $_POST['mf_ad_below_first_post_on'],
                                                'mf_ad_below_first_post'        => wp_kses_post($_POST['mf_ad_below_first_post_text']),
                                                'mf_ad_custom_css'              => strip_tags($_POST['mf_ad_custom_css'])
                                                );
```

And change to:

```
            $mingleforum->ads_options = array(  'mf_ad_above_forum_on'          => $_POST['mf_ad_above_forum_on'],
                                                'mf_ad_above_forum'             => $_POST['mf_ad_above_forum_text'],
                                                'mf_ad_below_forum_on'          => $_POST['mf_ad_below_forum_on'],
                                                'mf_ad_below_forum'             => $_POST['mf_ad_below_forum_text'],
                                                'mf_ad_above_branding_on'       => $_POST['mf_ad_above_branding_on'],
                                                'mf_ad_above_branding'          => $_POST['mf_ad_above_branding_text'],
                                                'mf_ad_above_info_center_on'    => $_POST['mf_ad_above_info_center_on'],
                                                'mf_ad_above_info_center'       => $_POST['mf_ad_above_info_center_text'],
                                                'mf_ad_above_quick_reply_on'    => $_POST['mf_ad_above_quick_reply_on'],
                                                'mf_ad_above_quick_reply'       => $_POST['mf_ad_above_quick_reply_text'],
                                                'mf_ad_above_breadcrumbs_on'    => $_POST['mf_ad_above_breadcrumbs_on'],
                                                'mf_ad_above_breadcrumbs'       => $_POST['mf_ad_above_breadcrumbs_text'],
                                                'mf_ad_below_first_post_on'     => $_POST['mf_ad_below_first_post_on'],
                                                'mf_ad_below_first_post'        => $_POST['mf_ad_below_first_post_text'],
                                                'mf_ad_custom_css'              => strip_tags($_POST['mf_ad_custom_css'])
                                                );
```

i think you can solve your problem who use mingle forum plugin.